# Android Sqlite singleton db filestream update failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application uses sqlite db, at first install I check If database folder nor db file exists If not call updateDB function. but some cases for example on galaxy note 10.1 It gaves me error.

on Load ;

```
    this.dhn = DataHelper.getDataHelper(this);

    File directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "XXX" + File.separator + "databases");
    if(!directory.exists())
    {
        directory.mkdirs();
        updateDB();
    }

    try {
        androidCheckout = this.dhn.Guid();

        if(this.dhn.getSettings("dbVersion") == null || Integer.parseInt(this.dhn.getSettings("dbVersion")) != Version || !this.dhn.isTableExists("UserInfo"))
        {
            updateDB(); 
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {               
    try {
            updateDB();
            androidCheckout = this.dhn.Guid();
        }
    catch (SQLiteException e11)
        {   
            ManuelYukle();
        }

    }



  public void updateDB()
    {
      this.dhn.close();

        try {
            InputStream myInput;

                myInput = getAssets().open("XXX.db");

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = "/data/data/XXX/databases/"
                    + "XXX.db";

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            FileOutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
            buffer = null;
            outFileName = null;
            this.dhn.close();
            this.dhn = null;
            this.dhn = DataHelper.getDataHelper(this); <<<<<<<< HERE IT CRUSHS
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

DBHELPER CLASS >

```
    private static DataHelper singleton;

    public static DataHelper getDataHelper(Context context) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                    singleton = new DataHelper(context);
                    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(singleton.context);
                    singleton.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
            if(!singleton.db.isOpen()){
                    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(singleton.context);
                    singleton.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
            singleton.context = context;
            return singleton;
    }

    private DataHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
}
```

ERROR LOG FILE >

```
12-09 19:11:15.772: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6271): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption at line 48171 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/XXX/databases/XXX_db
12-09 19:11:15.772: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6271): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed, db=/data/data/XXX/databases/XXX_db
12-09 19:11:15.772: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6271): sqlite3_exec - Failed to set synchronous mode = 1(Normal) 
12-09 19:11:15.772: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6271): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption at line 48171 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/XXX/databases/XXX_db
12-09 19:11:15.772: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6271): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed, db=/data/data/XXX/databases/XXX_db
12-09 19:11:15.772: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6271): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
12-09 19:11:15.777: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(6271): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/XXX/databases/XXX.db
12-09 19:11:15.782: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(6271): deleting the database file: /data/data/XXX/databases/XXX.db
```

Comment: Hi Mert, Same problem here with galaxy note 10.1. Got solution!??

Comment: Is it possible this is a permissions issue? Can you write (and read) anything to that 'XXX' directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem `database disk image is malformed` while I was trying to access database when it was updating itself. So, I followed the below way.

1. `DataBaseHelper`

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.SQLException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

           private static final String TAG = DataBaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();
           private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";
           private static String DB_NAME = "XXX";
           private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
           private final Context mContext;

           public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
               super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
               DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
               this.mContext = context;
           }

           public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
               boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
               if (!mDataBaseExist) {
                   this.getReadableDatabase();
                   try {
                       copyDataBase();
                   } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                       throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
                   }
               }
           }

       private boolean checkDataBase() {
           SQLiteDatabase mCheckDataBase = null;
           try {
               String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
               File pathFile = new File(mPath);
               if(pathFile.exists()) {
                   mCheckDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
               }
           } catch (SQLiteException mSQLiteException) {
               Log.e(TAG, "DatabaseNotFound " + mSQLiteException.toString());
           }

           if (mCheckDataBase != null) {
               mCheckDataBase.close();
           }
           return mCheckDataBase != null;
       }

       private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
           final InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
           final String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
           OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
           byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
           int mLength;
           while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
               mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
           }
           mOutput.flush();
           mOutput.close();
           mInput.close();
       }

       public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
           final String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
           mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
           SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
           return mDataBase != null;
       }

       @Override
       public synchronized void close() {
           if (mDataBase != null)
               mDataBase.close();
           super.close();
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
   }
   ```
2. `DBAdapter`

   ```
   public class DBAdapter {

       private static final String TAG = DBAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
       private final Context mContext;
       private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
       private final DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

       public DBAdapter(Context context) {
           this.mContext = context;
           mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
       }

       public DBAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException {
           try {
               mDbHelper.createDataBase();
           } catch (IOException mIOException) {
               throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
           }
           return this;
       }

       public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
           try {
               mDbHelper.openDataBase();
               mDbHelper.close();
               mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
           } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
               Log.e(TAG, mSQLException.toString());
               throw mSQLException;
           }
           return this;
       }

       public void close() {
           mDbHelper.close();
       }
   }
   ```
3. `Abhan` Extended Application Class

   ```
   public class Abhan extends Application {

       public static final String TAG = Abhan.class.getSimpleName();
       public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
       private int androidVersion = 4;
       private DBAdapter dbAdapter = null;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           setAndroidVersion(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

           if(dbAdapter == null) {
               dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
               dbAdapter.createDatabase();
           }
       }

       public int getAndroidVersion() {
           return androidVersion;
       }

       public void setAndroidVersion(int androidVersion) {
           this.androidVersion = androidVersion;
       }

       public DBAdapter getDBInstatnce() {
           dbAdapter.open();
           return dbAdapter;
       }

       public void closeDataBase() {
           dbAdapter.close();
           if(DEBUG) {
               android.util.Log.d(TAG, "DataBase closed.");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. In your `AndroidManifest`, Declare `Abhan`

   ```
   <application
       android:name=".Abhan"
       android:allowBackup="false"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   ```
5. In Your `Activity`, Access Your database using `Application` Class

   ```
   private Abhan abhan;
   ```

In `onCreate`

```
    abhan = (Abhan) this.getApplication();
```

Now access your database transaction method like this.

```
   int currentDay = abhan.getDBInstatnce().getCurrentDay();
```

Here, `abhan.getDBInstatnce()` returns your `Database` instance which is single instance across your whole application and `getCurrentDay()` is my method, declared in `DBAdpater` which returns me a current day.

I hope this one can sort out your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue when I was using prefilled db. I just solved like this.

The problem was in the sqlite database, I think it was a bug in sqlite3 old versions, perhaps, prior to 3.6. What I did was, I recreated the database with [sqlite3 v3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)  and it works like a charm - And, dont forget to create [android_metadata table](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

It worked for me then,I hope this will help you.